# What's the proper way of using libcURL without the dlls?

Tags: c++, libcurl

recently managed to use a libcurl in a test program for downloading a files.
The code is this:

```
  CURL * curl;
  FILE * fout;
  CURLcode result;
  char * url = "http://blablabla.com/blablabla.txt";
  char filename[FILENAME_MAX] = "blablabla.txt";
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl)
  {
    fout = fopen(filename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fout);
    result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fout);
  }
```

and those things for directives:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

My question is how to make that I don't need to copy all of its dlls in the same dir with the exec to make it work:

```
libcurl.dll
libeay32.dll
libidn-11.dll
librtmp.dll
libssh2.dll
libssl32.dll
zlib1.dll
```

Cannot find info about that in the homesite (http://curl.haxx.se) of the library :|

Comment: Understand that I need the source code of the dlls but cannot find it. Downloaded curl-7.24.0-devel-mingw32 already but it's not there. Just random .a files

Comment: @1000Gbps No, you don't need the source code. The .a files are all you need. See Lightness's answer below.

Comment: Sorry, can't understand you, English is not my mature language

Comment: I have been researching this for a while and there is virtually no information on how to actually do this properly, despite all the pages out there with copies of the nearly useless instruction file that comes with CURL. I have run into problems with the build scripts and even compilation errors. For someone who has no experience with building CURL, static linking appears to be impossible and there isn't much information about it to be found.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mean, "how do I statically link libcurl"?

5.7 in the [FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html) says:

> When building an application that uses the static libcurl library, you must add `-DCURL_STATICLIB` to your `CFLAGS`. Otherwise the linker will look for dynamic import symbols. If you're using Visual Studio, you need to instead add `CURL_STATICLIB` in the "Preprocessor Definitions" section.

Answer (score -3):

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
CString strUser;
FILE *ftplister;
m_FTPUserName.GetWindowTextW (strUser);
CT2CA PUF_File_HostName(PUF_FIle_Host);
CT2CA FTP_UserName(FTP_USERNAME);
FTP_PASSWORD.Append(L":");
FTP_PASSWORD.Append(FTP_USERNAME);
CT2CA FTP_Password(FTP_PASSWORD);
CT2CA FTP_AddressName(FTP_Address);
CString strLocalFile;
CString strFileName;
m_FTPFileName.GetWindowTextW(strFileName);
strLocalFile.Append(FTP_FileName);
strLocalFile.Append(L"\\");
strLocalFile.Append(strFileName);
CT2CA PUF_LocalFile(strLocalFile);
//ofstream stream2(PUF_LocalFile);

curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl)
{
    ftplister=fopen(PUF_LocalFile,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL,PUF_File_HostName);
    if(strUser!=_T(""))
    {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_USERPWD,FTP_Password);
    }
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, TRUE);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, ftplister);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(ftplister);
}
```

Comment: Above code is working fine download files to server and another thing without username and password(i.e anonymous )also working fine above code.